# lxml find method operates differently whether I'm building a tree or parsing a file

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I'm writing some Python code that will sometimes build an xml tree from scratch, and sometimes parse existing xml and update or report on it. The problem I'm having is that the lxml find and findall methods seem to operate differently depending on whether I've constructed the tree in memory, or whether I've parsed it from a file. Namespaces seem to be the issue. The namespace is defined at the root element (no prefixes). When I use find on an element from a tree constructed in memory, adding the namespaces keyword with the root nsmap results in searches returning nothing, but when omitted it returns the expected result. When the tree is parsed from a file however, the exact opposite occurs.

Edit: I think what I'm missing here is I need to explicitly add namespaces to the child elements.
The code is a bit verbose for sharing here, but I've replicated the issue in a bodgy snippet below.

```py
from lxml import etree
import os

fname = 'test.xml'
if os.path.exists(fname):
    root = etree.parse(fname).getroot()
    try:
        print('no namespaces -', root.find('title').text) #this doesn't work
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
    try:
        print('namespaced -', root.find('title', namespaces=root.nsmap).text) #this works
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
else:
    root = etree.Element(
        'DC',
        nsmap={None: "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"})
    etree.SubElement(root, 'title').text = "A title"
    try:
        print('no namespaces -', root.find('title').text) #this works
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
    try:
        print('namespaced -', root.find('title', namespaces=root.nsmap).text) #this doesn't work
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
    tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(fname)
```

If you run the above once, it will find the title element and print the value using the unnamespaced find. But if you run it again, it will only find the title element using a namespaced find. Am I missing here?

Edit: I think what I'm missing is I need to explicitly add namespaces to the child elements when constructing the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your `title` sub element in the same namespace as `DC`.

What I usually do is use [`etree.QName()`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).

Try changing this:

```
etree.SubElement(root, 'title').text = "A title"
```

to this:

```
etree.SubElement(root, etree.QName("{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}title")).text = "A title"
```

Comment: With QName, there should be no curly braces: it should be `etree.QName("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", "title")`

Comment: @mzjn - Both ways (one arg with clark notation or two args with the uri and local name separate) are fine. The examples in the documentation use the single arg format. The [api docs](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.QName-class.html) say that the first arg can be text (clark notation), uri, or Element (to extract the tag name).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just like to avoid curly braces when possible. Duly upvoted!

Comment: I ended up "fixing" it with ```etree.SubElement(root, 'title', nsmap=root.nsmap).text = "A title"``` - does this seem wildly wrong?

Comment: @LachlanGlanville - That seems reasonable since the namespace is unprefixed. If for some reason the input changed and a prefix was used for the namespace, you may have an issue. You'd have to test it to be sure though.